# How to resolve conflicts between prettier and eslint

Tags: node.js, eslint, prettier

I have set up both prettier and eslint in my node.js project. But I am getting huge amounts of conflicts and syntax errors.

[image: snapshot]

I followed [dev.to](https://dev.to/studio_m_song/how-to-make-eslint-work-with-prettier-avoiding-conflicts-and-problems-57pi#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20most%20common,Prettier%20as%20a%20ESLint%20plugin.&text=Once%20it%27s%20installed%2C%20you%20have,module.) documentation to set up prettier and eslint and make them compatible with each other.

```
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
 env: {
  browser: true,
  commonjs: true,
  es2021: true,
 },
 extends: ['standard', 'prettier'],
 overrides: [],
 parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 'latest',
 },
 rules: {
  'prettier/prettier': 'error',
  quotes: ['error', 'single'],
  semi: ['error', 'always'],
 },
 plugins: ['prettier'],
};

//.prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
 trailingComma: 'es5',
 tabWidth: 1,
 semi: true,
 singleQuote: true,
};
```